# How can I calculate the time dilation factor for velocities as low as 10 m/s?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I need to calculate time dilation factors; I tried using my calculator but for some reason my calculator cannot go that low when the velocity is on the order of 10 m s<sup>-1</sup>. What mathematical techniques can I use in this case?

Comment: It would help if you put in the equation that you are using. I expect a McLauren/Taylor expansion or more 'ad-hoc' expansion may be useful...

Comment: Not sure what your question is. But piece of paper can do, you're interested in a order of magnitude calculation, I presume, so just keep the factors of $10$'s and forget about the rest. An alternative is python.

Comment: Bingo @pfnuesel for "use paper" .

Comment: calculator cannot go so low? I assure you it can, just isolate for $|\gamma-1|$

Comment: I have a [TI 36X Solar](http://www.amazon.com/Texas-Instruments-TI36X-Scientific-Calculator/dp/B00000JBNM) calculator, and it handles finding $\gamma$ for $v=10$ m/s just fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about calculation instead of physics.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed the case that calculating quantities of the form
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-1
$$
using finite precision will fail when $v/c$ is low enough. In these cases, you should use the [binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\approx1+\frac12\frac{v^2}{c^2}+O(v^4/c^4),
$$
which works for small $v/c$.